# submitting a form with an onclick on a div

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick

```
<div onclick="javascript:document.form5577.submit(); return false">
<form action="https://www.url.com/" method="post" id="form5577">
Blah
</form>
</div>
```

I have this on my ASP.NET site and have tried a number of variations (including putting the div inside of the form) the I've seen but I can't get it to work. It's just a div that needs to submit a form on click.

Comment: Does it work if you remove `return: false`?

Answer (score 2):

```
<div onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('form5577').submit();">
<form action="https://www.url.com/" method="post" id="form5577">
Blah
</form>
</div>
```